# How to spyOn property of a Service that is a BehaviorSubject/Observable?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

First of, `spyOnProperty` is giving me `Property user does not have access type get` with this line: `spyOnProperty(userService, 'user', 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(adminUser));`

I have a UserService with a `user` property as such:

```
export class UserService {
  user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(new User());
}
```

The component that I'm testing needs to change behavior depending on the result of `userService.user.subscribe`. Hence, I need to be able to spy on `user`.

One idea that I had was to write a method getter, eg `getUser()` on class UserService, and don't access `user` via a property.

But that seems to be a bit extreme.

Any ideas?

Comment: BehaviorSubject has a `getValue()` method, not `get`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use spyOnProperty to return user object's mock.

```
spyOnProperty(userService.user, 'value', 'get').and.returnValue({ 'username': 'username'});
```

Answer (score 0):

create spy object as below

```
 let userSpy = new User(); // object that you want to hold in behaviorSubject of the spyObject of service   
    let userServiceSpy = {
    ...jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService',
    ['MethodListToSpyIfAny']),
    user : of(userSpy)
    }
```